# How to write IF THEN DO statement of SAS in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I have a `SAS code` which I want to convert into `SQL code`. I am stuck at one of the function in SAS which is `IF THEN DO`. The code looks like this:

```
IF FLAG = 'Y' AND ACCT = ' ' THEN DO;
ORIG_AMT = -(ORIG_AMT);
BAL = -(BAL);
AVAIL_BAL = -(AVAIL_BAL);
PROC_AMT = -(PROC_AMT);
END;
```

Please suggest how to convert this code into a `SQL server` code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: may [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms182717.aspx) can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this logic is in a data set, then you are working with columns.  If so, you can use the `case` statement in a `select`:

```
select (case when FLAG = 'Y' AND ACCT = ' ' then - orig_amt else orig_amt end) as orig_amt,
       (case when FLAG = 'Y' AND ACCT = ' ' then - bal else bal end) as bal,
       (case when FLAG = 'Y' AND ACCT = ' ' then - avail_bal else avail_bal end) as avail_bal,
       (case when FLAG = 'Y' AND ACCT = ' ' then - proc_amt else proc_amt end) as proc_amt
```

Comment: In SAS, a missing string is represented by `' '` (that's a quoted single space - see http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002316433.htm). If the string is empty (i.e. zero-length), then in SQL Server the test will be `ACCT = ''` (no space) but if it is `NULL` (i.e. missing) then the test will be `ACCT IS NULL`.

Comment: thank you so much @Gordon. This was very helpful. I would like to go with your answer as am more comfortable with case statements. Appreciate your help! Great forum!

Comment: @Josh thank you so much for your valuable comment. It was very helpful. Appreciate your help!